# Adding to an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5

I have created the array `var aData = [];` and I want to add to the array using a web service. I've used the following code which retrieves the last item:

```
var GSUserAfterFindRecord = function (sender) {
    UserVM.ModelList = ko.observableArray(UserVM.Model.GetDataList());
    var list = {};

    $.each(UserVM.Model.GetDataList(), function (index, item) {
        list = { name: item.Name };
    });
    aData.push(list);
    oModel.refresh();
}
```

But I want to retrieve all items not just the last. Instead of `list = { name: item.Name };` I've tried `list += { name: item.Name }` but that returns a blank table. I've used `console.log` to see what is being pushed to aData and when adding the + I get: `["[object Object][object Object][object Object][obje…ect][object Object][object Object][object Object]"]` without the + I get `[Object]`.

I should mention that I am using a sapui5 table that is why I have `oModel.refresh` but I think this can be done without knowing the fact that I am using a sapui5 table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make the `list` object into an array (it is currently a `object`) and then move the `push` part into the each loop, you will be able to add each item to the array.
The `Array.prototype.push` method adds one item to the array.

```
var list = [];
$.each(UserVM.Model.GetDataList(), function (index, item) {
    list.push({ name: item.Name });
});
```

Or just use the `aData` array in the each loop instead of creating a new temporary array!

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! I just changed `list` to `aData`. Works like a charm. I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

list[name] = item.Name; instead of list = { name: item.Name };